# Not able to render todoItems

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating Todo App using React

Below is my container file: App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';

class App extends Component{
  state ={
    todoItem: []
  }
  addTodoHanlder = event => {
    let todosValue = event.target.value;
    let newTodos = this.state.todoItem.push(todosValue)
    this.setState({
      todoItem: newTodos
    })
  }


render(){
  return(
    <div>
      <input type="text" />
      <button onClick={this.addTodoHanlder}>AddTodo</button>
      <Hello todos={this.state.todoItem}/>
    </div>
  )
}
}
render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Below is my Hello component:

```
import React from 'react';

const hello = (props) => {
  return(
    <div>
      <ul>
        {props.todos.map(todo => {
          return (
            <li>{todo}</li>
          )
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

export default hello;
```

I am getting this error: TypeError
props.todos.map is not a function

Can someone help me out with this and explain what exactly is happening and how can I render my todoItems?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is how you're modifying the array. The return value of `push` is the value of what you're pushing. So where you're trying to append to the array you're storing that appended value, not the new array.

```
let newTodos = this.state.todoItem.push(todosValue) # newTodos = todosValue
```

My suggestion would be to treat the state as immutable and create a new object which you can append to.

```
let newTodos = this.state.todoItem.slice();
newTodos.push(todosValue);
this.setState({
  todoItem: newTodos
});
```

You can also use the ES6 spread operator if you're using ES6.

```
let todosValue = event.target.value;
this.setState({
  todoItem: [...this.state.todoItem, todosValue]
})
```

You are also going to experience problems in rendering your todo items. The `event.target` is the button you're clicking. You'll want to pull from the input instead to store the todo text.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this was very helpful. I used ES6 concept suggested by you, however I made few modification to make this work.
I used another variable to store my input text and then clear it after everytime the state has been changed.

Updated App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Hello from "./Hello";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    todoItem: [],
    **todoText: ""**
  };
  addTodoHanlder = event => {
    let todoValue = this.state.todoText;
    this.setState({
      todoItem: [...this.state.todoItem, todoValue]
    });
    this.clearTodoText();
    **todoValue = "";**
  };

  **clearTodoText() {
    this.setState({ todoText: "" });
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ todoText: event.target.value });
  };**

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter Todo"
          **value={this.state.todoText}
          onChange={this.handleChange}**
        />
        <button onClick={this.addTodoHanlder}>AddTodo</button>
        <Hello todos={this.state.todoItem} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Changes made have been highlighted.